# Passing list to a Spring Controller using Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We have multiple `ModelBean` classes in our code. WE need to send different classification of data to Main `modelBean` class (like `list`, `object`, `string` etc) using `AJAX` call. I tried the below code and able to send `String` type but not `list` or `object`.  From `AJAX`, we need to send to `Spring controller`. The main Bean class is `MainBean`.

```
public class MainBean {

private String name;
private List<Truck> truckList;
private Address address;

}
public class Address {
    private String houseNumber;
    private String area;
    private String city;
}

public class Truck {
    private String truckName;
    private Type type;
}

public class Type{
    private String medium;
    private String heavy;
}
```

---

### CONTROLLER CLASS

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveData(@ModelAttribute("mainBean")MainBean mainBean){

        truckService.saveData(mainBean);

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/main");
    }
```

---

### AJAX Code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var url = window.location;

// SUBMIT FORM
$("#customerForm").submit(function(event) {
    // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
    event.preventDefault();
    ajaxPost();
});


function ajaxPost(){

    // PREPARE FORM DATA
    var formData = {
        firstname : $("#name").val(),
        truckName :  $("#truckName").val(),
        medium :  $("#medium").val(),
        heavy :  $("#heavy").val(),
        houseNumber :  $("#houseNumber").val()
    }

    // DO POST
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : url + "/postcustomer",
        data : JSON.stringify(formData),
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(result) {
            if(result.status == "Done"){
                $("#postResultDiv").html("<strong>" + "Success" + "</strong>");
            }else{
                $("#postResultDiv").html("<strong>Error</strong>");
            }
            console.log(result);
        },
        error : function(e) {
            alert("Error!")
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        }
    });
}

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need send you data as String to the controller, once your have the data into your controller you can parse it to List, or whatever type you want like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveData(@ModelAttribute("mainBean")String mainBeanString){


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<MainBean> itemsFromController = mapper.readValue(mainBeanString, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, MainBean.class));
    truckService.saveData(itemsFromController);

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/main");
}
```

**ObjectMapper** is from jackson library

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

[EDIT]:

Create the same model that you have created in java:

```
var mainBean = {
    name: "",
    truckList: [],
    address: {}
}
```

then you can pass the values like this:

```
mainBean.address.houseNumber = $("#houseNumber").val();
```

once you have created your model in Javascript you can put it to the ajax call

```
data : JSON.stringify(mainBean)
```

Comment: If I have one list, then it is fine. Look at my MainBean class and its associated other bean classes. For EX: How to send values to Address?

Comment: MainBean.Adress adress = new MainBean.Adress(), make sure you have defined getters and setters for you inner classes and then
adress.setArea("51");

Comment: MainBean.Adress adress = new MainBean.Adress().. wont work. I also tried after you suggestions.  Also please note that I am getting values from AJAX (plz update code above if possible).